# why Behavior of sprintf and snprintf is different when we use same source and destination?

Tags: c, printf

I have a simple code which uses sprintf

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main()
    {

            char str_src [1024]={"Hello"};
            sprintf(str_src,"%s%s",str_src,"hiiiiiiiiiii");
            printf("result = %s",str_src);  

    }
```

When i compile i get correct result :

> result = Hellohiiiiiiiiiii

But since sprintf is unsecure, i decided to change this to snprintf. I thought it would be really simple. I changed sprintf to snprintf like below

```
snprintf(str_src,1024,"%s%s",str_src,"hiiiiiiiiiii");
```

Now If i compile and run the code, i get different result

> result = hiiiiiiiiiii

I face this problem if i use str_src as 4th parameter (as a value to %s). Its suprising why the behavior of snprintf is different than sprintf?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's *undefined behavior* to use the same buffer both as destination and source.

From the C11 specification (7.21.6.6/2):

> If copying takes place between objects that overlap, the behavior is undefined.

The same is said for `snprintf` (7.21.6.5/2), and also on the `va_list` variants as well.

Unfortunately it's all to common in running code, but it can't really be relied on to work.

Comment: As a side note, program will crash on `OSX 10.9` if buffers overlap.

Answer (score 5):

From `sprintf` manpage:

> C99 and POSIX.1-2001 specify that the results are undefined if a call
>   to sprintf(), snprintf(), vsprintf(), or vsnprintf() would cause
>   copying to take place between objects that overlap (e.g., if the
>   target string array and one of the supplied input arguments refer to
>   the same buffer). See NOTES.

There's really no answer for this question, because your code has undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

No, you get *totally arbitrary* result in both cases, because it is Undefined Behaviour. One of them *happens* to be what you want. You may get different result on different computer. For what it's worth, it may format your hard drive and still be correct behaviour. Just don't use overlapping source and destination.