# C++ ifstream with a variable filename

Tags: c++

I'm trying to open a file whose name is composed by constant and variable parts.

My actual code is

```
char filename[100];
char extension1[] = ".pdb";
vector<string> id;

//code to find the ids(it works)

sprintf(filename, "/home/giovanni/Scrivania/enzimi/ligan/%s", id[1].c_str());
sprintf(filename, "%s%s", filename,extension1);
```

The problem is that filenames becomes

> .pdbe/giovanni/Scrivania/enzimi/ligan/102M

instead of

> /home/giovanni/Scrivania/enzimi/ligan/102M.pdb

Comment: You can't use the same string both as destination and an argument in `sprintf`, that is [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). In your case you might `strcat` instead.

Comment: Although I believe that too, could you please give a more detailed explanation? The documentation at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/ does not mention this.

Comment: A better solution would be to use [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream).

Comment: @Codor cplusplus.com is not the "official" documentation. It's a third party website.

Comment: @remyabel Yes I am aware of this.

Comment: The C++ specification explicitly says it's undefined.

Comment: [This answer explains why.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19490200)

Comment: @Codor The man pages are more reliable, i.e., "C99 and POSIX.1-2001 specify that the results are undefined if a call to sprintf(), snprintf(), vsprintf(), or vsnprintf() would cause copying to take place between objects that overlap (e.g., if the target string array and one of the supplied input arguments refer to the same buffer)."

Comment: And if you really want to continue using `sprintf`, why not simply do it in the first `sprintf`? Like e.g. `snprintf(filename, sizeof(filename), "/som/path/%s%s", id[1].c_str(), extension1);`

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, the C++ standard doesn't say anything explicit about `sprintf`, it just refers to the C99 standard.

Comment: @JonathanWakely Well, I knew that *at least* one of the standards mentioned it, just didn't remember which one it was. :)

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, luckily someone linked to a good answer of yours which explains it, so I've voted that up :)

Comment: @JonathanWakely Oh, that link was to an answer of mine? I didn't check it. :)

Answer (score 3):

Simply use std::string:

```
string filename = "/home/giovanni/Scrivania/enzimi/ligan/" + id[1] + ".pdb";

...

std::ifstream file(filename.c_str());
```

Comment: I've tried this too, but it gives me the same problem :(

Comment: Does `id[1]` perhaps contain a newline, spaces or null characters at the end?

Comment: Does operator+() do the right thing, if we have operator+( char*, std::string )?

Comment: @MichaelCrawford: Yes, as long as at least one side is a `std::string`

Comment: @Wintermute...probably yes, because it's a file written in colums, so, I think, I've id[1]\n.

Comment: You'll have to remove that, then, with something like `if(!id[1].empty() && *id[1].rbegin() == '\n') { id[1].resize(id[1].size() - 1); }`. Or read it in a manner that doesn't preserve the newline, such as `std::getline` from a `std::ifstream` (I suspect that you're using `fgets` from `FILE*` or so, because your code looks rather C-ish).

Answer (score 1):

Simply using this code would do (`sprintf` takes variable number of arguments):

```
sprintf(filename,"/home/giovanni/Scrivania/enzimi/ligan/%s%s", id[1].c_str(), extension1);
```

But, as you are using C++, Doing it in C style is not preferable. `sprintf()` can cuase buffer overflows and you can you safer version `snprintf()`. Best option would be to use `std::string`

Answer (score 1):

C99  and  POSIX.1-2001 specify that the results are undefined if a call  to sprintf()/snprintf would cause copying to take place between objects that overlap (e.g., if the target string array and one of the supplied  input  arguments  refer  to  the same buffer).
So line **sprintf(filename, "%s%s", filename,extension1)** is illegal.
You can try other options like std::string.

Answer (score 0):

1. Watch Out For Buffer Overflow!
2. You need to append to the existing string; you need to know the number of characters in it, then offset the pointer you pass in to the second call to sprintf:

`int len = sprintf(filename, "/home/giovanni/Scrivania/enzimi/ligan/%s", id[1].c_str());
    sprintf(filename + len, "%s", extension1);`

(sprintf returns the number of characters written into the buffer, but does not include the NUL terminator.)

Note that the second call to sprintf only has one "%s".